# Contacts_table has no column named contacts_name,though I insert it

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-contentprovider

I was wondering if someone could help me.
I'm getting an error saying that column_name doesn't exist.
But I included it in my DatabaseCleint .I can not find any error.

My DatabaseClass:

```
    public final class DatabaseClient extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private SQLiteDatabase db;
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION=2;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Contacts";
private static final String TABLE_NAME = "Contacts_table";
private static final String COLUMN_NAME = "contacts_name";
private static final String COLUMN_NUMBER = "contacts_number";

public DatabaseClient(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

}




@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

     db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
    //execute the create table query
    db.execSQL( "CREATE TABLE  " + TABLE_NAME + " ( " + COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT, " + COLUMN_NUMBER + " TEXT " + " );" );


}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);

}
//add row to database
public  void addContact(String ContactName,String ContactNumber){
    ContentValues values=new ContentValues();
    values.put(COLUMN_NAME,ContactName);
    values.put(COLUMN_NUMBER,ContactNumber);
    db=getWritableDatabase();
    db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,values);
    db.close();
}

public Cursor getallData(){
    //open db for writting
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor res=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME,null);
    return res;
}
public int isTableExist(){
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME,null);
    int count=cursor.getCount();
    return count;
}
```

}

My Main Class is:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {


private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
RecyclerView contactList;
ArrayList<Contact> shareContacts;
PhoneBookAdapter adapter;
DatabaseClient mydatabase;
Boolean permission=false;
int exist;
private String mOrderBy=ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY;
private static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS=99;
//TextView textView = null;
// String DISPLAY_NAME = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME;
//String NUMBER = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.out);
    mydatabase=new DatabaseClient(this);
    exist=mydatabase.isTableExist();
    contactList = findViewById(R.id.contact_list);
    permission=checkContactsPermission();
    if (permission){
        if (exist == 0) {

            getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(1, null, this);
            displayAllContacts();
        }
    }else {
        if (exist==0){
            getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(1, null, this);
            displayAllContacts();
        }
    }
    displayAllContacts();

}

private void displayAllContacts() {
    List<Contact> contactListitems=new ArrayList<>();
    Contact contactitems;
    Cursor c=mydatabase.getallData();
    if(c!=null && c.getCount()>0){
        while (c.moveToNext()){
            String name=c.getString(0);
            String number=c.getString(1);
            contactitems=new Contact();
            contactitems.setName(name);
            contactitems.setPhoneNumber(number);
            contactListitems.add(contactitems);
        }
    }

    PhoneBookAdapter adapter=new PhoneBookAdapter(contactListitems,getApplicationContext());
    contactList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    contactList.setAdapter(adapter);
}


@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    if(id==1){
        return  new CursorLoader(this,ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                "upper(" +
                        Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + ")ASC");
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    if(data!=null && data.getCount()>0){
        while (data.moveToNext()){
            int hasPhoneNumber=Integer.parseInt(data.getString(data.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER)));
            if (hasPhoneNumber>0){
                String id=data.getString(data.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                String name=data.getString(data.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY));
                ContentResolver contentResolver=getContentResolver();
                Cursor phone_cursor=contentResolver.query(Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                        null, Phone.CONTACT_ID + "=?",new String[]{id},null);
                if (phone_cursor.moveToNext()){
                    String phoneNumber=phone_cursor.getString(
                            phone_cursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER)
                    );
                    phone_cursor.close();
                    mydatabase.addContact(name,phoneNumber);
                }

            }
        }
        displayAllContacts();
    }

}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {


}
public boolean checkContactsPermission(){
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        if(ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)){
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS},MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);
        }else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);
        }
        return false;
    }else {
        return true;

    }
}


@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode){
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS:{
            if ((grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {

                if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    exist=mydatabase.isTableExist();
                    if(exist==0){
                        getLoaderManager().initLoader(1,null, (android.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Object>) getApplicationContext());
                    }
                    return;
                }
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(this,"permission denied",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

}

It show me error:

```
   01-14 17:09:08.163 9576-9576/com.demo.democontactlist E/SQLiteLog: (1) table Contacts_table has no column named contacts_name
01-14 17:09:08.164 9576-9576/com.demo.democontactlist E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting contacts_name=Amma contacts_number=+880 1787-586488
                                                                        android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table Contacts_table has no column named contacts_name (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO Contacts_table(contacts_name,contacts_number) VALUES (?,?)
                                                                            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
                                                                            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:898)
                                                                            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:509)
                                                                            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
                                                                            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
                                                                            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
                                                                            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1499)
                                                                            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1371)
                                                                            at com.demo.democontactlist.DatabaseClient.addContact(DatabaseClient.java:54)
                                                                            at com.demo.democontactlist.MainActivity.onLoadFinished(MainActivity.java:121)
                                                                            at com.demo.democontactlist.MainActivity.onLoadFinished(MainActivity.java:32)
```

Comment: in the public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) place a log like

public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
{
   Log.d("Myapp","oncreate called");
  .....

and check in the logcat if its getting called... and you can force this to be called if you change the database version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the `onCreate` method is only automatically run when the database is created. Just changing the SQL used by `onCreate` will not apply the changes.

There are 3 quick and easy solutions, all will result in the loss of data. The solutions are:-

- Delete the App's data via settings.
- Uninstall the App via settings.
- If the `onUpgrade` is the typical DROP table(s) followed calling `onCreate`, then increase the Database version number.

After doing one the above rerun the App.

If you need to preserve the data then this [SQL As Understood By SQLite - ALTER TABLE](http://sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html), may be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Did you increase DATABASE_VERSION number after changing your database?
`onUpgrade()` gets called everytime version number increases.

Comment: Sorry if I didn't comment this. because I don't have enough reputation

Answer (score 0):

Just uninstall and install the app again and should work. Happen to me lots of times :)